# Multiple files in powershell

Tags: powershell

How to using multiple files in Powershell to ensure modularity?

function.ps1 could have all the utility functions?

command1.ps1 could have calls related to a command?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549516/run-a-powershell-script-from-another-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on how to write [PowerShell Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd901839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549516/run-a-powershell-script-from-another-one